# How do I uninstall PC BSD 10? Can I partition the drive after installing?

Tags: partition

I found a CD with that (PC BSD 10) written on it while looking for a back up of my husband's system disk. I installed it, only to find out it wasn't what I wanted. I'm not very techy. I can't find an uninstall command or option. So I wondered if I could partition the drive so that I could use two operating systems. Then I can load windows and use it to restore everything in a separate partition.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike software applications, operating systems do not have an uninstall command or option. Instead, you install another operating system over it.

The Windows installer has the tools to partition your drive, hence you can use it to create a number of partitions during the installation of the operating system.

If you only want Windows, then you can simply boot from the Windows CD/DVD/USB and do a clean install; meaning, select the option to use (and thus erase) the entire disk.

On the other hand, if there's content on the disk which you want to keep, then you'll need to choose the option to create a new partition for Windows. If there's content on the disk which you REALLY need to keep, then taking a backup should be first priority; I always mention this when dealing with partitions.